# How to write both h1 and h2 in the same line?

Tags: html, css

I have a page and I want simply to make a header. This header is an `<h1>` text aligned to the left, and an `<h2>` aligned to the right, in the same line, and after them, an `<hr>`. My code so far look as follows (if you test it, you'll see that it's wrong):

```
<h1 align="left">Title</h1> 
<h2 align="right">Context</h2> 
<hr/>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: do it with CSS

h1 {
   float left;
}
hr {
   clear: left;
}

Comment: just use` float: left` or `display: inline-block` h1,h2 elements css block

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Keyword `float`:

```
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;">Title</h1> 
<h2 style="text-align:right;float:right;">Context</h2> 
<hr style="clear:both;"/>
```

Comment: @Pekka it doesn't need `display:inline` at all. In fact, it's useless because floated elements are always `display:block`. Additionally (@Floern), unless you are setting widths on the headings the text alignment is meaningless too.

Comment: Friggin perfect mate

Comment: add margin-left:10px to h1,  and margin-right:10px to h2 elements

Comment: What does `clear:both` do?

Comment: what if its in the middle of each?

Answer (score 85):

`h1` and `h2` are native `display: block` elements.

Make them `display: inline` so they behave like normal text.

You should also reset the default `padding` and `margin` that the elements have.

Comment: If I just set it to `h1`, it makes no diference at all, and if I do it for both, I lose the alignment.

Comment: @Bruno I'm sorry, I misread your requirement. `float` will fix it, see @Floern's answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃, +1 For simple solution. You saved my time.

Comment: Actually this solution solves the problem better than the one marked as the answer.

Comment: As an example for other noobs like me (maybe someone will correct me), `<h1 style="display: inline">Title</h1>` `<h2 style="display: inline">Context</h2>`

Answer (score 8):

In many cases,

```
display:inline;
```

is enough.

But in some cases, you have to add following:

```
clear:none;
```

Comment: Inline elements cannot clear floats, so whether you have `clear: none` or even something that isn't `none` on an inline element doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

You can use flexbox. So put the `h1` and `h2` in a container with an id of `container` then add this code:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In answer the question heading (found by a google search) and not the re-question
To stop the line breaking when you have different heading tags e.g.

```
<h5 style="display:inline;"> What the... </h5><h1 style="display:inline;"> heck is going on? </h1>
```

Will give you:

What the...heck is going on?

and not

```
What the... 
heck is going on?
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<h1 style="text-align: left; float: left;">Text 1</h1>
<h2 style="text-align: right; float: right; display: inline;">Text 2</h2>
<hr style="clear: both;" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `float: right` will negate the effects of `display: inline`, making it useless.