# How do I make a <h2> and a <button> appear on the same line?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In my Bootstrap 3 web page, I have an h2 header and then a drop button ...

```
<h2>Employees</h2>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle" type="button"
        data-toggle="dropdown">
        Config Menu <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"  onclick="openAddNewEmployee()">Add New Employee ...</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The drop-down appears on the next line, below the h2.

How do I get the drop-down to appear to the right of the h2 instead on of the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this other answered question and it helped: [How to write both h1 and h2 in the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736067/how-to-write-both-h1-and-h2-in-the-same-line)

In the end, this was my solution ...

```
<h2 style="text-align:left;float:left;padding-right:25px">Employees</h2>
<div class="dropdown"style="text-align:left;float:left;margin-top:20px">
    <button class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle" type="button"
        data-toggle="dropdown">
        Config Menu <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"  onclick="openAddNewEmployee()">Add New Employee ...</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr style="clear:both;"/>
```